# Android App and Baby Meta Sites

Tags: feature-request, android-app, per-site-meta

I would like to see the ability to switch between a site and its meta quickly in the android app instead of individually pinning the meta to the "Your Sites" tab.

Users who have high reputation in any site are generally more prone to use the meta of that site.

Please implement this feature.